# Adding File Type in Function parameter gives different results than defining explicitly

Tags: powershell, function

I am trying to create a simple powershell function that allows you to define the following parameters:

1. Directory to recurse
2. File age
3. File type(s)

The function will then delete the files identified.  I am having an issue when identifying the files to delete.  This should be fairly simple and does work as expected if i run the script directly.  When running the script as a function and passing parameters, i receive file types other than the ones defined and am unsure why this is occurring.

Simplified version of code that is trying to identify the files:

```
Function CleanLogfiles($targetFolder, $daysOlderThan, $fileType)
{
$now = Get-Date
$lastWrite = $now.AddDays(-$daysOlderThan)
Get-ChildItem $targetFolder -Include $fileType -Recurse |  Where-Object {-not $_.PSIsContainer}  | Where-Object {$_.lastwritetime -le $lastWrite}
}

CleanLogFiles("C:\\Windows\\Logs", 1, "\*.log")
```

Code above will display multiple file types (.log files, .etl files and .xml files).

If i change the following statement to explicitly define the $fileType parameter within the code block instead of using a variable, it works as expected and only displays .log files.
See below:

**From:**

```
Get-ChildItem $targetFolder -Include $fileType -Recurse |  Where-Object {-not $_.PSIsContainer}  | Where-Object {$_.lastwritetime -le $lastWrite}
```

**To:**

```
Get-ChildItem $targetFolder -Include "\*.log" -Recurse |  Where-Object {-not $_.PSIsContainer}  | Where-Object {$_.lastwritetime -le $lastWrite}
```

If additional explanation is needed, please let me know.

Any assistance would be appreciated.

Comment: Unlike other languages, arguments are space delimited not comma delimited and the parentheses are not needed. Right now you're passing `"C:\\Windows\\Logs", 1, "\*.log"` as a single argument bounded to `$targetFolder`. `CleanLogFiles "C:\\Windows\\Logs" 1 "\*.log"` is how you should call your function.

Comment: Results are now as expected.  Thank you for the help!!!